# Passing subject line to view_email_url landing page

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, landing-page

We just noticed that when we use the 'view online' link in our emails, the page title is based on whatever we have in the template that the email uses. Unfortunately we were just using the title of the template in the title HTML, so our audience sees it says 'Template XYZ' or whatever, which isn't great.

Does anyone know of a way to get the page title to use the subject line from the email instead?

Answer (score 4):

There is no way for a user to change this title in a View as Web Page (VAWP) link as this is autogenerated by SFMC.  You could talk to your account rep and see if there is anything they can do to allow you to edit this field - but I don't believe this is possible.

Also, the subjectline is not accessible natively - like email name, data source, etc. You would either need to store the subject in a DE or set it inside of the email as an AMPScript variable and then use that variable in the subject line field and inside the email.